# Arduino trim() and replace() methods returns conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'String' requested

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to remove the newline character \n from the end of my string.

```
myString = Serial1.readString();
String myString_trim = xbeeString.replace("\n", "");
```

I keep getting this error when using either the .trim() or .replace() methods.

Error:

```
exit status 1
conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'String' requested
```

Comment: The [`replace`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/replace/) function does in-place replacement. It doesn't return a new string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Same with the [`trim()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/trim/) function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`replace`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/replace/) method changes existing string, but not returns a new one.

```
myString = "123\n";
myString.replace("\n", "");
assert(myString == "123");
```